# appending list of lists to pd.Dataframe()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having trouble `list` of `lists` to `pandas` DataFrame.

here is my data:

```
list_of_lists = np.array(hazard)
[['13-06-2016' '2.0' '1.0' '3.0' '88.0' '0.0' '72.0' '7.27']
 ['18-06-2016' '1.0' '0.0' '3.0' '85.5' '0.0' '77.0' '8.05']
 ['22-06-2016' '3.0' '0.0' '5.0' '91.5' '0.0' '66.0' '7.54']
 ['26-06-2016' '3.0' '2.0' '4.0' '89.6' '1.0' '74.0' '10.0']
 ['01-07-2016' '3.0' '0.0' '1.0' '88.9' '0.0' '72.0' '6.75']
 ['27-08-2016' '7.0' '4.0' '2.0' '81.8' '2.0' '91.0' '8.79']
 ['01-09-2016' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '59.3' '1.0' '46.0' '6.92']
 ['11-09-2016' '2.0' '1.0' '4.0' '91.7' '0.0' '71.0' '6.84']
 ['16-09-2016' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '81.8' '1.0' '68.0' '7.07']
 ['24-09-2016' '2.0' '0.0' '1.0' '84.2' '0.0' '52.0' '6.11']
 ['30-10-2016' '3.0' '3.0' '5.0' '83.0' '1.0' '72.0' '8.87']
 ['05-11-2016' '3.0' '3.0' '1.0' '94.6' '0.0' '75.0' '9.76']
 ['09-11-2016' '1.0' '1.0' '4.0' '92.1' '0.0' '84.0' '7.21']
 ['20-11-2016' '0.0' '0.0' '5.0' '84.6' '1.0' '92.0' '8.27']
 ['26-11-2016' '2.0' '1.0' '1.0' '81.8' '0.0' '46.0' '7.19']
 ['26-12-2016' '5.0' '2.0' '4.0' '85.7' '1.0' '87.0' '10.0']
 ['31-12-2016' '2.0' '1.0' '5.0' '86.0' '1.0' '65.0' '7.78']
 ['04-01-2017' '2.0' '0.0' '1.0' '83.6' '1.0' '81.0' '6.07']]
```

and I have a `pandas` dataframe that I have constructed as

```
player_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Total Shots', 'On Target',
                                      'Key Passes', 'Passing Accuracy', 'Aerials Won',
                                      'Touches', 'WhoScored Rating'])
```

now when I try `player_df.append(list_of_lists)`
I get,

> TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object.

can someone tell me what is going wrong here? the length of the lists matches with the number of columns here so surely it should be fine?

Answer (score 23):

The error is telling you that you need a pandas NDFrame object which most commonly is a DataFrame. Try converting your list of lists to a dataframe and then appending

```
player_df.append(pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=player_df.columns))
```

Comment: Correct as always. Thanks!

Comment: Important to remember that this will not modify `player_df` in place, but only return the appended df.

Comment: Quoting [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/13083583):
As of pandas 2.0, `append` (previously deprecated) [was removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).
You need to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead (for most applications)