# Error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I am trying to append a dictionary to a DataFrame object, but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

As far as I know, DataFrame does have the method "append".

Code snippet:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df).append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

I was expecting the dictionary `new_row` to be added as a new row.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I imagine you use pandas 2.0, please make it explicit in your question (and question title)

Comment: Also give an example of `new_row` for clarity. You might need to use `pd.DataFrame([new_row])` or `pd.DataFrame(new_row)` depending on the format.

Answer (score 329):

As of pandas 2.0, `append` (previously deprecated) [was removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

You need to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead (for most applications):

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
```

[As noted by @cottontail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132725/16343464), it's also possible to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), although this only works if the new index is not already present in the DataFrame (typically, this will be the case if the index is a `RangeIndex`:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = new_row # only use with a RangeIndex!
```

##### Why was it removed?

We frequently see new users of [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) try to code like they would do it in pure Python. They use [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to access items in a loop (see [here](/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) why you shouldn't), or `append` in a way that is similar to python [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

However, as noted in pandas' issue [#35407](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407), **pandas's `append` and `list.append` are really not the same thing**. `list.append` is in place, while pandas's `append` creates a new DataFrame:

> I think that we should deprecate Series.append and DataFrame.append.
> They're making an analogy to list.append, but it's a poor analogy
> since the behavior isn't (and can't be) in place. The data for the
> index and values needs to be copied to create the result.
>
> These are also apparently popular methods. DataFrame.append is around
> the 10th most visited page in our API docs.
>
> Unless I'm mistaken, users are always better off building up a list of
> values and passing them to the constructor, or building up a list of
> NDFrames followed by a single concat.

As a consequence, while `list.append` is [amortized O(1)](/questions/33044883/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-pythons-list-append-method-o1) at each step of the loop, **pandas' `append` is `O(n)`, making it inefficient when repeated insertion is performed**.

##### What if I need to repeat the process?

Using `append` or `concat` repeatedly is not a good idea (this has a [quadratic behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower) as it creates a new DataFrame for each step).

In such case, the new items should be collected in a list, and at the end of the loop converted to `DataFrame` and eventually concatenated to the original `DataFrame`.

```
lst = []

for new_row in items_generation_logic:
    lst.append(new_row)

# create extension
df_extended = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# or columns=df.columns if identical columns

# concatenate to original
out = pd.concat([df, df_extended])
```

Comment: when I collect the data in a list and THEN convert the data to a dataframe - then I do not see the benefit of pandas at all. I have the lists and can plot them etc

Comment: @Alex that's absolutely true, if you can perform your workflow without pandas then just do so. Pandas is a convenience to manipulate data, but if you already have lists or arrays and no pandas operations to run, then don't use pandas! [tag:matplotlib] for instance works very well with lists/dictionaries/arrays.

Comment: I opened issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/57849 to bring back append. This was a sensibly named method that did what its name implied. Performance concerns should have been addressed by improving append(). I am now forced to fix broken code that used to be perfectly fine. The fix makes the code more verbose and less readable.

Comment: @ArenCambre I think the idea was to push people to refactor the code to avoid needing `append`. Could you provide a [mre] version of your code (open a new question) to see if it can be refactored?

Comment: @ArenCambre btw, is downvoting this answer because you're upset that append was removed really relevant?  ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've already refactored my code.

Answer (score 59):

**Disclaimer:** this answer seems to attract popularity, but the proposed approach **should not be used**. `append` was not *changed* to `_append`, `_append` is a private **internal** method and `append` was **removed** from pandas API. The claim *"The `append` method in pandas look similar to *list.append* in Python. That's why append method in pandas is now modified to `_append`."* is utterly incorrect. The leading `_` only means one thing: the method is **private** and is not intended to be used outside of pandas' internal code.

---

In the new version of **Pandas**, the `append` method is changed to `_append`. You can simply use `_append` instead of `append`, i.e., `df._append(df2)`.

```
df = df1._append(df2,ignore_index=True)
```

**Why is it changed?**

The `append` method in pandas looks similar to *list.append* in Python. That's why the *append* method in pandas is now modified to `_append`.

Comment: This is a private method and thus not part of the official API. It cannot be used reliably (the method could be changed or removed without notice). TBH, almost every time someone asked a question about `append` here, there was a better alternative than using it.

Comment: I added a disclaimer to the answer. We now start seeing question using `_append` on SO, which is a fully incorrect use of the API. `_append` is not intended to be part of the public API. `append` was already leading to bad code, please do not encourage other to do even worse…

Comment: Can you please explain why "append" was leading to bad code? I am new to pandas, but for me  append looks very reasonable.

Comment: @Nils I explained it in [my answer](/a/75956237/16343464), unlike `list.append` for which appending an item is in place and amortized, `DataFrame.append` was creating a new DataFrame for each step. Thus, in a loop the complexity is quadratic (1+2+3+4+...).

Comment: This is easier than switching to concat for fixing old code. Ty

Comment: @gumdropsteve easier until the internal pandas code changes and this breaks… Also the important part is that `append` is inefficient. You should rather seize the opportunity to fix the code. If you have old code that you don't want to update, use an old version of the library.

Comment: 64 upvotes on this, and 51 of those came *after* someone pointed out that it's completely wrong and added a disclaimer... I guess people really don't care about what is correct or proper practice, they just want to copy and paste something that seems to give the right result, until it breaks and they can go looking again. I wish people understood that programming is about **thinking**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's sad indeed, especially since the main reason for wanting to use this seems to be maintenance of existing code. If you have working code and want it to remain functional, then **freeze the working version of the library**. Don't update and expect the code to still work.

Answer (score 37):

If you are enlarging a dataframe in a loop using `DataFrame.append` or `concat` or `loc`, consider rewriting your code to enlarge a Python list and construct a dataframe once. Sometimes, you may not even need `pd.concat`, you may just need a DataFrame constructor on a list of dicts.

A pretty common example of appending new rows to a dataframe is scraping data from a webpage and storing them a dataframe. In that case, instead of appending to a dataframe, literally just replace dataframe with a list and call `pd.DataFrame()` or `pd.concat` once at the end once. An example:

So instead of:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()       # <--- initial dataframe (doesn't have to be empty)
for url in ticker_list:
    data = pd.read_csv(url)
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)  # <--- enlarge dataframe
```

use:

```py
lst = []                  # <--- initial list (doesn't have to be empty; 
for url in ticker_list:   #                    could store the initial df)
    data = pd.read_csv(url)
    lst.append(data)                         # <--- enlarge list
df = pd.concat(lst)                          # <--- concatenate the frames
```

Data reading logic could be response data from an API, data scraped from a webpage, whatever, the code refactoring is really minimal. In the above example, we assumed that `lst` is a list of dataframes but if it were a list of dicts/lists etc. then we could use `df = pd.DataFrame(lst)` instead in the last line of code.

---

That said, if **a single row** is to be appended to a dataframe, `loc` could also do the job.

```py
df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
```

With the `loc` call, the dataframe is enlarged with index label `len(df)`, which makes sense only if the index is `RangeIndex`; `RangeIndex` is created by default if an explicit index is not passed to the dataframe constructor.

A working example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': list('abc')})
df.loc[len(df)] = [4, 'd']
df.loc[len(df)] = {'A': 5, 'B': 'e'}
df.loc[len(df)] = pd.Series({'A': 6, 'B': 'f'})
```

[image: result]

As pointed out by @mozway, enlarging a pandas dataframe has O(n^2) complexity because in each iteration, the entire dataframe has to be read and copied. The following perfplot shows the runtime difference relative to concatenation done once.<sup>1</sup> As you can see, both ways to enlarge a dataframe are much, much slower than enlarging a list and constructing a dataframe once (e.g. for a dataframe with 10k rows, `concat` in a loop is about 800 times slower and `loc` in a loop is about 1600 times slower).

[image: perfplot]

<sup>1</sup> The code used to produce the perfplot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def concat_loop(lst):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
    for dic in lst:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([dic])], ignore_index=True)
    return df.infer_objects()
    
def concat_once(lst):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(lst)], ignore_index=True)
    return df.infer_objects()

def loc_loop(lst):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
    for dic in lst:
        df.loc[len(df)] = dic
    return df


perfplot.plot(
    setup=lambda n: [{'A': i, 'B': 'a'*(i%5+1)} for i in range(n)],
    kernels=[concat_loop, concat_once, loc_loop],
    labels= ['concat in a loop', 'concat once', 'loc in a loop'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(16)],
    xlabel='Length of dataframe',
    title='Enlarging a dataframe in a loop',
    relative_to=1,
    equality_check=pd.DataFrame.equals);
```

Comment: I quoted your answer in mine to give some more details on when `loc` can be used. Let me know if you want to edit it (or feel free to do it).

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the heads up. I'll come around to editing my post when I have the time.