# no object to append to

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make an etl script but when running the extract function im getting this error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

the function

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import glob

def extract_from_csv(file_to_process):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_to_process)
    return dataframe

def extract():
    extracted_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Term", "Amount"]) 
    
    for csvfile in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        extracted_data = extracted_data.append(extract_from_csv(csvfile), ignore_index=True)
        
    return extracted_data
```

I don't know what to try this is function i have been using for the past two etl scripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataFrame object has no attribute append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Comment: I used the concat in place to append and still got the same erroor

Comment: That's incredible! Please show us the full Traceback. Edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear way you could achieve your result:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import glob

def read_csv(csv_file):
    return pd.read_csv(csv_file, columns=["Term", "Amount"])

def extract():
    dfs = [read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('*.csv')]
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```