# Replacing .append with .concat in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fix the code I've posted below. It works properly and my CSV file exports as intended, but I get a warning in my terminal: "The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead."

I reviewed the examples in the documentation and another thread on Stack Overflow, but I am having trouble getting the concat to actually work. It won't accept a data frame object so I have tried to convert to a list but I'm having a difficult time getting things to work like they do now. Could anyone help me replace this bit of code with the more future proof concat method?

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range (2013,2023):
    year = str(i)
    url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_'+year+'_skaters.html'

    df = pd.read_html(url,header=1)[0]
    df['year'] = year
    result = result.append(df, sort=False)

result = result[~result['Age'].str.contains("Age")]
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)

result.to_csv('hdb_data.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it has been removed in `2.0.0` (see [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append/75956237#75956237) and [*GH35407*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407)) :

```
list_dfs = []

for year in range (2013, 2023):
    url = f"https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_{year}_skaters.html"
    list_dfs.append(pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0].assign(year=year))

result = (pd.concat(list_dfs).loc[lambda x: ~x["Age"].str.contains("Age")]
              .reset_index(drop=True))

result.to_csv("hdb_data.csv", index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(result)

         Rk             Player Age   Tm Pos  ...  HIT FOW FOL    FO%  year
0         1  Justin Abdelkader  25  DET  LW  ...  120  65  60   52.0  2013
1         2          Luke Adam  22  BUF  LW  ...    3   1   0  100.0  2013
2         3        Craig Adams  35  PIT  RW  ...  107  51  47   52.0  2013
...     ...                ...  ..  ...  ..  ...  ...  ..  ..    ...   ...
10370  1002          Artem Zub  26  OTT   D  ...  155   0   0    NaN  2022
10371  1003    Mats Zuccarello  34  MIN  LW  ...   36  21  34   38.2  2022
10372  1004       Jason Zucker  30  PIT  LW  ...   66   4  11   26.7  2022

[10373 rows x 29 columns]
```