# While appending 2 dataframes getting "ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe 1 is inside a function and Dataframe 2 is in main function when I run main function, it appends the values from a JSON and stores in `result_df` and getting `ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns` error

Why I am creating Dataframe2 in main function?
I am using Dataframe2 (total_device_df) in other functions to convert to csv.

**Reproducible code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

class KatsRequest:

currDir = os.getcwd()
    def parse_json_response():

        filename = "my_json_file.json"
        device_name = ["Trona", "Sheldon"]
        "creating dataframe to store result"
        column_names = ["DEVICE", "STATUS", "LAST UPDATED"]
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
        my_json_file = currDir + '/' + filename

        for i in range(len(device_name)):
            my_device_name = device_name[i]
            with open(my_json_file) as f:
                data = json.load(f)

            for devices in data:
                device_types = devices['device_types']
                if my_device_name in device_types['name']:
                    if device_types['name'] == my_device_name:
                        device = devices['device_types']['name']
                        last_updated = devices['devices']['last_status_update']
                        device_status = devices['devices']['status']

                        result_df.loc[len(result_df)] = {'DEVICE': device, 'STATUS': device_status, 'LAST UPDATED': last_updated}
        return result_df

def main()
    total_device_df = pd.DataFrame()
    total_device_df.loc[len(total_device_df)] = KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my JSON file contents: (save in your current path named as "my_json_file.json")

```
[{"devices": {"id": 34815, "last_status_update": "2023-05-25 07:56:49", "status": "idle" }, "device_types": {"name": "Trona"}}, {"devices": {"id": 34815, "last_status_update": "2023-05-25 07:56:49", "status": "idle" }, "device_types": {"name": "Sheldon"}}]
```

**Output:**
`ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns`

What is missing/wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your example is not reproducible)

You have to use `pd.concat` if you want to use merge `total_device_df` and the dataframe returned by `parse_json_response`.

```
def main():
    total_device_df = pd.DataFrame()
    total_device_df = pd.concat([total_device_df, KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)])
```

Or simply:

```
def main():
    total_device_df = pd.DataFrame()
    total_device_df = KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)
```

Full example:

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

currDir = os.getcwd()
filename = 'my_json_file.json'
device_names = ['Trona', 'Sheldon']

class KatsRequest:
    def parse_json_response(self, filename, device_name):

        # creating dataframe to store result
        column_names = ["DEVICE", "STATUS", "LAST UPDATED"]
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
        my_json_file = currDir + '/' + filename

        for i in range(len(device_name)):
            my_device_name = device_name[i]
            with open(my_json_file) as f:
                data = json.load(f)

            for devices in data:
                device_types = devices['device_types']
                if my_device_name in device_types['name']:
                    if device_types['name'] == my_device_name:
                        device = devices['device_types']['name']
                        last_updated = devices['devices']['last_status_update']
                        device_status = devices['devices']['status']

                        result_df.loc[len(result_df)] = {'DEVICE': device, 'STATUS': device_status, 'LAST UPDATED': last_updated}
        return result_df

def main():
    total_device_df = pd.DataFrame()
    total_device_df = pd.concat([total_device_df, KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)])
    print(total_device_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
>>> total_device_df
    DEVICE STATUS         LAST UPDATED
0    Trona   idle  2023-05-25 07:56:49
1  Sheldon   idle  2023-05-25 07:56:49
```

**Update**:

A painless way is to use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
with open('my_json_file.json') as jp:
    data = json.load(jp)
total_device_df = (pd.json_normalize(data).loc[lambda x: x['device_types.name'].isin(device_names)]
                     .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.', maxsplit=1)[-1].upper()))
```

Output:

```
>>> total_device_df
      ID   LAST_STATUS_UPDATE STATUS     NAME
0  34815  2023-05-25 07:56:49   idle    Trona
1  34815  2023-05-25 07:56:49   idle  Sheldon
```

> How to use pd.json_normalize method in full example code?

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

currDir = os.getcwd()
filename = 'my_json_file.json'
device_names = ['Trona', 'Sheldon']

class KatsRequest:
    def parse_json_response(self, filename, device_name):

        # creating dataframe to store result
        dmap = {
            'device_types.name': 'DEVICE',
            'devices.status': 'STATUS',
            'devices.last_status_update': 'LAST STATUS'
        }
        my_json_file = currDir + '/' + filename

        with open(my_json_file) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        results_df = (pd.json_normalize(data)[dmap.keys()].rename(columns=dmap)
                        .loc[lambda x: x['DEVICE'].isin(device_names)])
        return results_df

def main():
    total_device_df = pd.DataFrame()
    total_device_df = pd.concat([total_device_df, KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)])
    print(total_device_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem is I am using pandas >2.0 and hence according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append/75956237#75956237 concat and append has been deprecated and i guess thats the reason

Comment: `concat` is not deprecated! `append` has been removed!

Comment: I tried, but below error were thrown,

`    self.device_dsn = devices['devices']['dsn']
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'dsn'`


any idea, why?

Comment: Because there is no key dsn in your json?

Comment: there is dsn key in my json, also 'dsn' is displayed in this print statement `print(total_device_df)` along with other details. but what could be the reason for  this error to show up

Comment: Try to use `pd.json_normalize`, it could be easier to debug.

Comment: can you please update how to use pd.json_normalize method in full example code?

Comment: I updated my answer according your request. Can you check it please?

Comment: how can we ignore index in this?
 result_df.loc[len(result_df)] = {'DEVICE': device, 'STATUS': device_status, 'LAST UPDATED': last_updated}

could that be the reason for this error?
`self.device_dsn = devices['devices']['dsn'] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'dsn'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253837/discussion-between-mdi-and-corralien).