# pandas columns division returns multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I am trying to simply divide two columns element-wise, but for some reason this returns two columns instead of one as I would expect.

I think it has something to do with the fact that I need to create the dataframe iteratively, so I opted for by appending rows one at a time. Here's some testing code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()])

# Create a DataFrame
data = {
    'dataset': ['177.png', '276.png', '208.png', '282.png'],
    'partition': ['green', 'green', 'green', 'green'],
    'zeros': [1896715, 1914720, 1913894, 1910815],
    'ones': [23285, 5280, 6106, 9185],
    'total': [1920000, 1920000, 1920000, 1920000]
}

for i in range(len(data['ones'])):
    row = []
    for k in data.keys():
        row.append(data[k][i])
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)

df_check = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_check["result"] = df_check["zeros"] / df_check["total"]

df["result"] = df["zeros"] / df["total"]
df
```

If you try to run this, you'll see that all work as expected with `df_check` and the code fails when it get to `df["result"] = df["zeros"] / df["total"]`:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column result
```

In fact, If I try to inspect the result of the division I notice there are two columns with all missing values:

```
>>> df["zeros"] / df["total"]

    total   zeros
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
```

Any suggestion why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()])
```

the `split()` method create a list itself, so avoid the list and use the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns='image_name partition zeros ones total'.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

You logic to set up the dataframe is incorrect, don't use a loop, directly go for the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, optionally with an extra step to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'dataset': 'image_name'})
df["result"] = df["zeros"] / df["total"]
```

Output:

```
  image_name partition    zeros   ones    total    result
0    177.png     green  1896715  23285  1920000  0.987872
1    276.png     green  1914720   5280  1920000  0.997250
2    208.png     green  1913894   6106  1920000  0.996820
3    282.png     green  1910815   9185  1920000  0.995216
```

With your current approach you end up with a MultiIndex with a single level, which causes the further issue (slicing `df['zeros']` and `df["total"]` gives you two **DataFrames**, not Series, and the division is not aligned).

```
print(df.columns)

MultiIndex([('image_name',),
            ( 'partition',),
            (     'zeros',),
            (      'ones',),
            (     'total',)],
           )
```

In any case [`append` is now deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! your suggestion helped me solving the problem. The split method already creates a list, so I was passing a list with one list as columns.

Comment: @Luca exactly, but honestly don't do this, a loop+append is really not the right approach ;) If you want to set up the column names manually just do it after: `df = pd.DataFrame(data) ; df.columns = 'image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()` ;)

Comment: The fact is I need to loop to get the data. So I can "append" data at each iteration to some lists and then create the dataframe all at once at the end, is that what you mean? because otherwise I wouldn't know how to get the data...

Comment: Then better loop to create the dictionary, **then** pass it once to the DataFrame constructor. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/16343464) on the deprecation of `append` and how to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue thanks to the suggestion in @mozway answer.

Indeed the problem is in the fact that the bugged version has a MultiIndex. However, this is due to how I specify columns list and not due to the append method per-se. It solved changing from

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()])
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["image_name", "partition", "zeros", "ones", "total"])
```

or even just `columns='image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()`.

Comment: Problem is `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['image_name partition zeros ones total'.split()])` return `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[["image_name", "partition", "zeros", "ones", "total"]])`, need `df = pd.DataFrame(columns='image_name partition zeros ones total'.split())`