# How to add a value of a column from one Dataframe to another column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, append

1st dataframe: Output

```
A B C 
M  2 H
```

2nd Dataframe: Campaign details

```
P Q R
2 3 O
```

A, B, C in one dataframe is same as the column in the 2nd dataframe, but with different name, I want to add another row to the 2nd dataframe

**Output

```
P Q R
2 3 O
M 2 H
```

Please assume A = P, B = Q and C = R

I am trying this but not working

```
output["A"] = Campaign_Details["P"].apply(lambda x: Campaign_Details.get(x)).append
```

With this , all the rows in P column are replaced by:

```
<bound method Series.append of Unnamed: 1 N...
```

Is there any other way to do this???

Comment: *assume A = P, B = Q and C = R*. Do you mean A = P because you define it or because A and P are the first column and so on?

Comment: I define it. It needless not to be in sequence

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with set same columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
out = pd.concat([Campaign_Details, output.set_axis(Campaign_Details.columns, axis=1)],
                ignore_index=True)
print (out)
   P  Q  R
0  2  3  O
1  M  2  H
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) based on your desired mapping (A->P, B->Q, C->R), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
# mapping for the names
d = {'A': 'P', 'B': 'Q', 'C': 'R'}

out = pd.concat([Campaign_Details, Output.rename(columns=d)],
                ignore_index=True)
```

*NB. if you want to merge in order of the columns, you could also define `d = dict(zip(Output.columns, Campaign_Details.columns))`.*

Output:

```
   P  Q  R
0  2  3  O
1  M  2  H
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are the right way to merge your dataframe. You have to use `pd.concat` (see below why) but they don't explain your error.

`append` is a method not an attribute, so you have to call the method with `(...)`. However it's not sufficient. What do you want to append? It's like `list` in python:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2]
lst.append(3)
print(lst)

# Output
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Instead of adding column by column with `apply`, you can directly `append` your `Output` dataframe to `Campaign_Details`. To do it, you have to rename the column of `Output` dataframe to align their column names with `Campaign_Details`

@mozway uses a mapping dict to be sure A=P, B=Q and C=R. On the other side, @jezrael considers A=P because A and P are the first columns and so on.

With `append`:

```
out = Campaign_Details.append(Output.set_axis(Campaign_Details.columns, axis=1))
print(out)

# Output
   P  Q  R
0  2  3  O
0  M  2  H
```

Maybe Pandas will raise a `FutureWarning`. If you use a version of Pandas prior 2, you can use `append` but [this method has been removed from Pandas 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/15239951) so the right way is to use `pd.concat`.