# AWS Lambda Function Not Allowing DF.Append() or row addition through loc

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently using pandas within AWS Lambda to create functions in python. I currently have a dataframe and am looking to append a new record to the dataframe. Outside of Lambda, I would normally just append the record to the dataframe. In AWS Lambda, I am using the following code and getting the following error message:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'], sep=',')
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    
    first_name = 'Steve'
    last_name = 'Jobs'
    name = (first_name + " " + last_name)
    firm = 'Apple'
    position = 'CEO'
    product = 'Macintosh'
    date_sent = today
    type = 'StreetCat Generated'
    
    current_list = [{'Name': name, 'Firm': firm, 'Position': position, 'Product': product, 'Date Sent': date_sent, 'Type': type}]
    df2 = df.append(current_list)
```

The error message I get is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "7c1a322c-b194-4588-8fce-6aa64a666052",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 36, in lambda_handler\n    df2 = df.append(current_list)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/core/generic.py\", line 5989, in __getattr__\n    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I also tried to manually add the record to the dataframe using the following code:

```
current_list = [{'Name': name, 'Firm': firm, 'Position': position, 'Product': product, 'Date Sent': date_sent, 'Type': type}]
df2 = df.loc[len(df.index)] = [current_list]
```

When I attempt to do this, I get an error that there is a mismatch in the number of columns and the row cannot be set. I printed the shape of each of these objects and confirmed they are the same size. Does anybody have suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the below post, It explains that the append method was deprecated in previous pandas versions and in the most recent is removed (concat method is suggested to use). Also explains how to use loc in order to add a new record to an existing dataframe.

[DataFrame object has no attribute append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append)