# 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am getting the following error:

```
attributeerror: 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'append'
```

when using `concat` and `_append` function in the code below. The output produces a blank dataset (see image below).

How should I resolve this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

final=pd.DataFrame()
for j in range(1,800):

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win 64 ; x64) Apple WeKit /537.36(KHTML , like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'}
response=requests.get('https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?campaign=desktop_nav&page={}',headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
company=soup.find_all('div',class_='company-content-wrapper')
name=[]
rating=[]
reviews=[]
ctype=[]
hq=[]
how_old=[]
no_of_employee=[]

for i in company:
    name.append(i.find('h2').text.strip())
    rating.append(i.find('p',class_='rating').text.strip())
    reviews.append(i.find('a',class_='review-count').text.strip())
    info_entities=i.find_all('p',class_='infoEntity')
    if len(info_entities)>0:
        ctype.append(info_entities[0].text.strip())
    else:
        ctype.append("N/A")

    if len(info_entities)>1:
        hq.append(info_entities[1].text.strip())
    else:
        hq.append("N/A")

    if len(info_entities)>2:
        how_old.append(info_entities[2].text.strip())
    else:
        how_old.append("N/A")

    if len(info_entities)>3:
        no_of_employee.append(info_entities[3].text.strip())
    else:
        no_of_employee.append("N/A")

dataset=pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':name,
    'Rating':rating,
    'reviews':reviews,
    'Company Type':ctype,
    'Headquaters':hq,
    'Company Age':how_old,
    'No. of Employee':no_of_employee
})

final=pd.concat([final,dataset],ignore_index=True)
print(final)
final.to_csv('Company_Dataset.csv')
```

[image: Blank dataset output]

Answer (score 0):

This Python script works just fine from my laptop (with light changes in indentation with the outer `for` loop to make it works), output .csv doesn't blank.
As you've mentioned, append is removed previously and concat is used instead from April 2023. On Stackoverflow we can find this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append) . So I don't think that's the problem.

Can you try rerun with smaller list of pages, modify your question with a proper format of your code, or give any other information? Here is your code I've used to run (I just change use a list of pages number to see the output quickly)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

final = pd.DataFrame()

for j in [1, 2, 600, 601]:
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win 64 ; x64) AppleWeKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?campaign=desktop_nav&page={j}', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    company = soup.find_all('div', class_='company-content-wrapper')
    name = []
    rating = []
    reviews = []
    ctype = []
    hq = []
    how_old = []
    no_of_employee = []

    for i in company:
        name.append(i.find('h2').text.strip())
        rating.append(i.find('p', class_='rating').text.strip())
        reviews.append(i.find('a', class_='review-count').text.strip())
        info_entities = i.find_all('p', class_='infoEntity')
        if len(info_entities) > 0:
            ctype.append(info_entities[0].text.strip())
        else:
            ctype.append("N/A")

        if len(info_entities) > 1:
            hq.append(info_entities[1].text.strip())
        else:
            hq.append("N/A")

        if len(info_entities) > 2:
            how_old.append(info_entities[2].text.strip())
        else:
            how_old.append("N/A")

        if len(info_entities) > 3:
            no_of_employee.append(info_entities[3].text.strip())
        else:
            no_of_employee.append("N/A")

    dataset = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': name,
        'Rating': rating,
        'Reviews': reviews,
        'Company Type': ctype,
        'Headquarters': hq,
        'Company Age': how_old,
        'No. of Employees': no_of_employee
    })

    final = pd.concat([final, dataset], ignore_index=True)

final.to_csv('Company_Dataset_2.csv', index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Milan - You mis-typed the proper formatting of your response. You wrote:

```
response=requests.get('https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?campaign=desktop_nav&page={}',headers=headers).text
```

When you should have this: a f-string with j into curly brackets.

```
response=requests.get(f'https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?campaign=desktop_nav&page={j}',headers=headers).text
```

SophieTP corrected the error in their answer, hence the lack of error for them.
When correcting for that, it works perfectly well.