# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'datetime.datetime'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-forecast

I'm trying to use AWS Amazon Forecast in the Amazon_Forecast_Quick_Start_Guide but am running into an error which I don't know how to fix.

This is the code:

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'value', 'source'])

for index, row in actuals.iterrows():
    clean_timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row['timestamp'])
    results_df = pd.concat({'timestamp' : clean_timestamp , 'value' : row['target_value'], 'source': 'actual'} , ignore_index=True)
for index, row in forecasts_p10_df.iterrows():
    clean_timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row['Timestamp'])
    results_df = pd.concat({'timestamp' : clean_timestamp , 'value' : row['Value'], 'source': 'p10'} , ignore_index=True)
for index, row in forecasts_p50_df.iterrows():
    clean_timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row['Timestamp'])
    results_df = pd.concat({'timestamp' : clean_timestamp , 'value' : row['Value'], 'source': 'p50'} , ignore_index=True)
for index, row in forecasts_p90_df.iterrows():
    clean_timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row['Timestamp'])
    results_df = pd.concat({'timestamp' : clean_timestamp , 'value' : row['Value'], 'source': 'p90'} , ignore_index=True)

pivot_df = results_df.pivot(columns='source', values='value', index="timestamp")

pivot_df.plot(figsize=(15, 7))
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'datetime.datetime'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Can someone help me fix this?

I tried running the code but am running into an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append' in Amazon\_Forecast\_Quick\_Start\_Guide Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825805/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append-in-amazon-forecast)

Comment: Why ask the same question twice?

Comment: Don't use `concat` in a loop, this has the worst complexity. Why not use `actuals['clean_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(actuals['timestamp'])`?