# I want to append y to the 1st column of DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df = ({'a':[0,1,4],'b' : [10,2,5]})
y = [5,6]                

for i in y:
    x = df._append([{df.columns[0]: i}], ignore_index = True)
print(x)
```

Result is :

```
{'a':[0,1,4,6],
 'b' : [10,2,5]}
```

Result Should be:

```
{'a':[0,1,4,5,6],
 'b' : [10,2,5]}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({df.columns[0]:y})])
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   0   10.0
1   1   2.0
2   4   5.0
0   5   NaN
1   6   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you use `_append`? This is an undocumented, private pandas method.

[`append` was removed from pandas API because it was used so badly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/16343464).

You should **never** append to a DataFrame iteratively.

The correct approach to perform this operation is [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
x = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'A': y})])
```

Output:

```
   A     B
0  0  10.0
1  1   2.0
2  4   5.0
0  5   NaN
1  6   NaN
```