# Add empty row between every new market

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change `.append` to `.concat`.
I got the following error `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 2, 2)`.
I looked already at [Error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/error-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append) I tried but unfortunately I got the error above. How do I fix this issue?

I want to add an empty row between every new `Market`.

Dataframe

```py
Market  Values
0      A       1
1      B       2
2      A       3
3      C       4
4      B       5
```

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Market': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
    'Values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_sorted)

markets = ['A', 'B', 'C']

appended_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through markets and append rows
for market in markets:
    market_rows = df_sorted[df_sorted['Market'] == market]
    #appended_df = appended_df.append(market_rows, ignore_index=True) # <--- old
    df_sorted = pd.concat([df_sorted, pd.DataFrame([market_rows])], ignore_index=True)
    #appended_df = appended_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True) # <--- old
    df_sorted = pd.concat([df_sorted, pd.DataFrame([pd.Series()])], ignore_index=True)
print(appended_df)

[OUT] ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 2, 2)
```

What I want

```py
 Market  Values
0      A     1.0
1      A     3.0
2    NaN     NaN
3      B     2.0
4      B     5.0
5    NaN     NaN
6      C     4.0
```

Comment: @cottontail "*I want to add an empty row **between** every new Market.*", I guess this is to act a a delimiter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in a loop, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to efficiently split the groups (rather than repeated slicing), collect in a list and `concat` once after the loop. Use a nested loop to add the intermediate (and discard the last one before `concat`):

```
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = pd.concat([x for k, g in df_sorted.groupby('Market', sort=False)
                for x in [g, pd.DataFrame(index=[0])]][:-1],
               ignore_index=True
              )
```

Output:

```
  Market  Values
0      A     1.0
1      A     3.0
2    NaN     NaN
3      B     2.0
4      B     5.0
5    NaN     NaN
6      C     4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly!
Is it still possible to sort in descending order? So that `C` starts at the beginning. 
I have sorted it before, but after the code snippet the sorting is reversed again.

Comment: @Test of course, if the groups are already sorted, simply pass `sort=False` to `groupby` to keep the current order

Answer (score 1):

Non loop solution - create helper `df1` DataFrame with indices by last duplicated values of `Market`s and apapend to original with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_sorted = df_sorted.sort_values('Market', ignore_index=True)

idx = df_sorted.drop_duplicates('Market', keep='last').index[:-1]

out = (pd.concat([df_sorted, pd.DataFrame(index=idx)])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True))
print (out)
  Market  Values
0      A     1.0
1      A     3.0
2    NaN     NaN
3      B     2.0
4      B     5.0
5    NaN     NaN
6      C     4.0
```

Comment: Note that this requires to have a sorted index (if you have a custom one this would not work)

Comment: @mozway - In sample data is not custom index, I prefer thissolution because groupby is slow and possible avoid here.