# Yahoo Finance API get_quote_table not working

Tags: pandas, dataframe, stock, yahoo-finance

I am trying to import stock information from Yahoo finance through its API. I tried `get_quote_table` but it says:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'.
> Did you mean: '_append'?

Does anyone know what is the problem?
I updated my pandas and checked my python version too.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd

quote = si.get_quote_table('AAPL')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [last update](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-fin/#history) of `yahoo-fin` package is Jul 10, 2021 so it's incompatible with newer versions of Pandas. If you really need to use this library, downgrade your version of Pandas to 1.5.3:

```
[...]$ pip install "pandas<2"
```

[Error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/15239951)