# Attribute Error is 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have trying to this code to run jupyter notebook:

```
for i in range(1, 429):
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=<api_key>&language=en-US&page={}'.format(i))
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['results'])[['id', 'title', 'overview', 'release_date', 'vote_average', 'vote_count']]
    df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

but throw to error is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `out = [] ; for i in range(1, 429): out.append(pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=<api_key>&language=en-US&page={}'.format(i)).json()['results'])[['id', 'title', 'overview', 'release_date', 'vote_average', 'vote_count']]) ; df = pd.concat(out)`

Comment: [error-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/error-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append)